# Combining multiple Property-Based Filters for Rsyslog

Tags: rsyslog, syslog

I was trying to set up a specific Rsyslog configuration file to catch all incoming kernel messages of a few types. For example, I want to dump all logs containing "example message 1" and "example message 2" into a custom log.

For example, this rule in rsyslog.conf works.

```
:msg, contains, "example message 1" /var/log/custom-log
:msg, contains, "example message 2" /var/log/custom-log
```

However, is there a way to make it any cleaner? For example, using `"example message 1"|"example message 2"` as a value instead, or something equivalent. The rsyslog documentation is a tad cryptic about this.

Thanks!

Comment: Clarification: you want to dump all logs containing either "example message 1" **OR** "example message 2" into a custom log, right?

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well:

```
if $msg contains ['string 1', 'string 2'] then /var/log/somelog
```

Or maybe some other inspiration:  https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/filters.html